# SQL Syntax Error 1064 (MyBB)

Tags: syntax, mysql-error-1064

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ORDER BY price ASC' at line 1

Query:
SELECT * FROM mybb_newpoints_subscriptions WHERE sid IN() ORDER BY price ASC
```

Code snip:

```
$subplans = '';

    if($sids != '')
    {
        $where = 'sid IN('.implode(',', $sids).')';

        $query = $db->simple_select('newpoints_subscriptions', '*', $where, array('order_by' => 'price', 'order_dir' => 'ASC'));
        while ($sub = $db->fetch_array($query))
```

How can I fi​​​​x th​​​is? It's been a​​​ problem for a while and ​​​​​​​​I am not very experienced with P​​HP. If you need more d​​​​eetz let me k​​​​​now. Th​​​anks! :)​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: (How do *you* read `error in your SQL syntax; check [near ') ORDER…]
Query:
SELECT * FROM … WHERE sid IN() ORDER`?)

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: What does your SQL manual have to say about `WHERE <expression> IN…`? How does that compare to the expanded SQL in the error message?

Comment: I have no idea how to check that. :P

Comment: As long as you have problems to use the documentation of products you use ("SQL manual") as well as to make intelligible what you are referring to (`check that`? *What* `that`?), programming will prove hard.